# C# and delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to use a delegate which allows me to seach for a match on one item in a list with another item in the other list by using FIND.

I have got the code working as follows:-

```
Type a = listname.Find(delegate(Type b))
{
         return list.item == b.list.item;
}
```

If the list item matches the item in b, then it returns the item in a.  This is working fine, however I now want to check that I only return a if more than one item in list.item matches b.list.item such as

```
Type a = listname.Find(delegate(Type b))
{
         return list.item == b.list.item;
                 list.anotheritem == b.list.anotheritem
}
```

I can't seem to code it so that it checks for more than one condition before returning Type a.

Comment: I think you should read about the logical operators of C#. check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Is the first example *actual working code*? I ask because it will not compile, it is missing a `);` at the end. Also, the description of what you want to do does not match the content of your code. I would expect your code to read something like "if the item I'm looking at in one list, passed in as a parameter, is equal to any of the items in that other list, then I want to return the item I'm looking at". But your code doesn't do that.

Comment: In other words, I would expect your code to be something like `.Find(delegate(Type item) { return b.list.Any(i => i == item); });`

Comment: What is `Type`? Did you define your own class called `Type`? Or is it actually `System.Type`? I ask because the former is a horrible idea, and the latter won't compile (since `System.Type` has not public member called `list`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Type a = listname.Find(delegate(Type b) 
{ 
         return list.item == b.list.item &&
                 list.anotheritem == b.list.anotheritem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the logical AND operator, &&.

```
     return list.item == b.list.item && 
            list.anotheritem == b.list.anotheritem
```

Answer (score 2):

```
     return list.item == b.list.item;
             list.anotheritem == b.list.anotheritem
```

should be

```
     return list.item == b.list.item &&
             list.anotheritem == b.list.anotheritem;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an `AND` operator instead of a semi-colon to combine the two conditions:

```
Type a = listname.Find(delegate(Type b)
{
         return list.item == b.list.item 
                && list.anotheritem == b.list.anotheritem;
}
```